# Hadoop setup in Windows on E-drive

Tags: hadoop

Is there possible to setup **Hadoop single node** on apart from C drive in windows?. My C drive will be almost full storage.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop doesn't require any specific volume/drive to run on.

You can define `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, `hadoop.tmp.dir` and related storage locations anywhere.

It's recommended not to use singluar disks or run Hadoop in Windows, though.